# swagger editor: missingProperty: required

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I am using openapi 3 and got an error:

```
should have required property 'required' 
missingProperty: required
```

Here is my file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
...
- name: count
  in: path
  description: "count"
  schema:
     type: boolean
```

If I add `required: false`, I got another error saying `required can only be true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Path parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters) are always required, so they must have `required: true`.